# how to create a column that determines if a value is missing in a variable in R

Tags: r, categories, flags

I am trying to identify if a column has a missing number category based on a `max.score`. Here is a sample dataset.

```
    df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3),
                 score = c(0,0,2,0,2, 0,1,1,0,1, 0,1,0,1,0),
                 max.score = c(2,2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2))
    
   > df
   id score max.score
1   1     0         2
2   1     0         2
3   1     2         2
4   1     0         2
5   1     2         2
6   2     0         1
7   2     1         1
8   2     1         1
9   2     0         1
10  2     1         1
11  3     0         2
12  3     1         2
13  3     0         2
14  3     1         2
15  3     0         2
```

for the `id` = `1`, based on the `max.score`, it is missing the category `1`. I would like to add `missing` column saying something like `1`. When `id`=`3` is missing `score` = `2`, the `missing` column should indicate a value of `2`. If there are more than one category is missing, then it would indicate those missing categories as ,for example, `1,3`. The desired output should be:

```
> df
   id score max.score  missing
1   1     0         2    1
2   1     0         2    1
3   1     2         2    1
4   1     0         2    1
5   1     2         2    1
6   2     0         1    NA
7   2     1         1    NA
8   2     1         1    NA
9   2     0         1    NA
10  2     1         1    NA
11  3     0         2    2
12  3     1         2    2
13  3     0         2    2
14  3     1         2    2
15  3     0         2    2
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: can you have more than 2 elements missing? eg what if for the first group the max score was 5?

Comment: that is a possibility. thanks

Comment: So would you want instead of missing 1 to have missing `1,3` or missing `1,max`. It is better to have missing `1,3` dont you think so?

Comment: eg in the final group 3, you should consider having `missing_2` rather than `missing_max` or if you are going to have more analysis, just have the column as missing ad the results as 2,3,4 etc

Comment: yes, let me change the description.

Comment: So you expect every ID to have have every value in the `score` column from `0` to `max.score`?

Comment: that is the expectation but some `id`s do not have those categories, s oI would like to see which ones have missing those categories.

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(missing = toString(setdiff(0:max.score[1], unique(score))),
         missing = ifelse(nzchar(missing), missing, NA))

     # A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
      id score max.score missing
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
 1     1     0         2 1      
 2     1     0         2 1      
 3     1     2         2 1      
 4     1     0         2 1      
 5     1     2         2 1      
 6     2     0         1 NA     
 7     2     1         1 NA     
 8     2     1         1 NA     
 9     2     0         1 NA     
10     2     1         1 NA     
11     3     0         2 2      
12     3     1         2 2      
13     3     0         2 2      
14     3     1         2 2      
15     3     0         2 2
```